# How to obtain json string during postback without using hidden fields?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json

This may seem like an odd question but I really do think it should be possible.

Here's the entire background that I would like to present so that you get a more clear understanding of what I'm trying to achieve.

I have a framework dll library which my project uses. 
Within the library, I have embedded a .js file(lets call it b.js) that creates a javascript object(bjobj) containing the api for all my redundant js required functionality.

The class library also contains a class(lets call it bpage) which extends the system.web.ui.page class and provides additional functionality.

Within bpage, i've created a property that wraps around a Dictionary and lets the page that extends bpage add structs, nullable structs and strings into the dictionary.

Once values are added to the dictionary, developers can now access the values in javascript via the api methods through bjobj object.

My bpage creates json string and sends it to bjobj using clientscript.register... methods.

No hidden variables are used and the json string is automatically recognized by the browser as a json object during parsing.

Doing this eliminates the need for using hidden variables on the page.

The one big drawback to this entire technique is that, the changes made to the variables on the browser, could not be retrived on the server since everything happens from the framework dll.

I now need a mechanism using which no changes need be done on the pages that extend bpage, yet from my framework cs code and js code, I could automatically get the changes made in the json object back on the server.

To achieve the intented functionality, I currently seem to require two functionalities.

Firstly, my bjobj needs to be able to automatically capture any postback events so that it can stringify the json objects prior the beggining of the postback.

Secondly, there must be some mechanism using which the stringified json can be sent back to the server without using hidden fields, so that my bpage can capture the string and deserialize it.

Please provide your insights into the technique I'm trying.
My aim is to make certain that my codebase looks much cleaner and development speed be improved.

Comment: TL;DR; seriously try updating the question

Comment: You could break down your question into parts. like first paragraph tells what you trying to do(about your task at hand), then next one tells the programming stuff,code snippets, then the third tells about what problems you facing with that code.. you can have more if have.. but just looking at large text all together scares people away.. wont even try to read.. forget understanding it..

Comment: That's what, the fifth question today I've seen that was monolithically paragraphed?

Comment: sorry guys, but I'm posting this question using my cell.

Unfortunately, the mobile site does not seem to allow as much formatting as the desktop site does. 
I currently have no other option so please bear with me.

Comment: Is there not anyone who can answer this question? I'll restate my main requirement. I need to be able to send data back to the server in an ASP.NET postback event without using any hidden fields at all. This is since the javascrit that will be executed that will contain json data will come directly from my dll. I don't want to leave any dependencies on the end developer who will use my dll to develop his web pages.